# Why my SIGHUP handler failed on child process after fork and exec?

Tags: c++, fork, exec

I try to make a C++ server demo that can restart after passing a SIGHUP signal in the terminal: `kill -SIGHUP xx_pid`, but it is weird that the SIGHUP signal can only be caught by the parent process. I use fork and exec function to generate the child process, also parent and child process execute the same code. Why my SIGHUP handler failed on the child process? How can I make it work on the child process. (The logic in sighup handler is fork and exec). Here is the code:

```cpp
void sighup_handler(int signo) {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    ...
    execve("./server", argv_cstr.get(), NULL)
}

int main() {
    // signal(SIGHUP, sighup_handler);
    struct sigaction action;
    action.sa_handler = restart_handler;
    sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);
    action.sa_flags |= SA_RESTART;
    action.sa_flags |= SA_RESETHAND;
    if (sigaction(SIGHUP, &action, NULL) < 0) {
        LOG(ERROR) << "Fail to register SIGHUP, abort";
        abort();
    }
    while (1) {
        std::cout << "a";
        usleep(1000 * 4000L);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I run the code in terminal: `./server`, its pid is 2899. After I type `kill -SIGHUP 2899`, it generate a child process 39875. But I go on `kill -SIGHUP 39875`, it doesn't work. Why? The child process also execute the whole codes, include the `signal(SIGHUP, restart_handler);` in the first line of `main()`, why only the parent process can handle SIGHUP signal?

Comment: If you use [`sigaction`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) (without setting the `SA_RESETHAND` flag) instead of [`signal`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) does it work then?

Comment: `action.sa_flags |= SA_RESTART;` leads to *undefined behavior* because you haven't initialized the whole structure. Define action as `sigaction action = {};` to make sure that it's all initialized, including setting the `sa_flags` member to zero

Comment: By the way, have you checked that `execve` actually succeeds? How do you check? Do you have some kind of error logging if `execve` fails (and actually returns)? And what is `argv_cstr`? What is its value? Are you sure that the new process is entering the infinite loop? Can you please try to create a proper [mre] to show us?

Comment: @Some programmer dude Yes, execve() is no problem, and after I remove `action.sa_flags |= SA_RESTART;`, the codes show some kind of chaos, it seems that when I send SIGHUP, the system default handler is executed first, which cause the parent process abort, then execute my self-defined sighup_handler.

Comment: @Some programmer dude Ok, I will write a detail example soon, thanks.

Comment: By the way, after I add a sa_flag: `action.sa_flags |= SA_NODEFER;`, it seems worked normal.